# Flume agent - [tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log] exited with 1

Tags: flume-ng

i am new to flume. My flume agent is not writing data to HDFS. Please help. Here is the code. The purpose of the code is to get the data from apache and park it to HDFS.

```
#identify the components on agent a1
a1.sources = apache_server
a1.sinks = hdfs_sink
a1.channels = c1

# Configure the source:
a1.sources.apache_server.type = exec
a1.sources.apache_server.command = tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log

# Describe the sink:

a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://hadoop1.example.com:9000/Apache_Logs
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 10
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.filePrefix=apacheaccess

# Configure a channel that buffers events in memory:

a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 20000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel:

a1.sources.apache_server.channels = c1
a1.sinks.hdfs_sink.channel = c1
```

Comment: Please share error log and also full command which you are executing

Comment: Are you sure 9000 is the correct port? I am able to successfully write to HDFS using port 8020 on the primary namenode.

When running flume-ng from the command line, is an error printed out?